# Can you find one of two resistances in a series circuit from the voltage, one resistance, and the voltage across the unknown resistor?

Tags: resistance

So I have a series circuit with two resistors...  One is serving as a current source for the unknown: a variable resistance.

Known are the voltage of the circuit, the fixed resistance, and the voltage across the unknown through an ADC.

Can I find the resistance of the unknown in real time from the voltage from the ADC?

Comment: `one is serving as a current source for the unknown` is not quite true ... the current flows through both resistors and is the same at any point ... the current is dependent on the total resistance and the power supply voltage .... google `ohms law`  and `serial and parallel resistance`

Comment: I mean in the same sense you need a resistor across the base of a BJT...

Comment: Maybe you'd better draw your circuit with the schematic editor. Circuits say more than 1000 words

Comment: no idea what you  are talking about now. ... there is no mention of BJT in the question .... please clarify your question ... draw a schematic diagram using the provided editor .... voting to close as `unclear what you are asking` ... when you clarify your question, I will remove the vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a series circuit then "one is serving as a current source" is not true. If it were then you'd need only know what that current is and use V=IR across the unknown resistor.

If you don't know the current, which is more likely, then you can still determine the resistance.

I'm assuming the circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fET0UU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Start with what you know:

```
Vin (known) = Vr1 (unknown) + Vr2 (known)
```

Vr1 is now known.

```
Vr1 (known) = Ir1 (unknown) * R1 (known)
```

Ir1 is now known.

```
Ir2 (unknown) = Ir1 (known)
```

Ir2 is now known.

```
Vr2 (known) = Ir2 (known) * R2 (unknown)
```

R2 is now known and you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much !!  ^_^  I'm kinda new to electronics, and while, intuitively, the math felt like it could work, I also had Ohms' Law in mind telling me I was outright missing a variable, and even though I knew current is equal across a series circuit, it wasn't striking me as the solution...  Thank you very much  x 3